# HaxeFlixel findPath

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I've got a little problem with the `findPath` function.

I'm working with a mix of two tutorials (one from Haxeflixel, and the second from haxecoder) and the second one uses CSV instead of Ogmo and uses a `findPath` when we click.

But when I click, the game crashes, nice.

This is my code: http://hastebin.com/xunidubiyi.avrasm

The problem is on the 86th line (split into multiple lines to fit the width):

```
var nodes:Array<FlxPoint> = _mWalls.findPath(
  FlxPoint.get(
    _player.x + 16 / 2,
    _player.y + 16 / 2
  ),
  FlxPoint.get(
    tileCoordX * 16 + 16 / 2,
    tileCoordY * 16 + 16 / 2
  )
);
```

Output:

```
Invalid field access : allowCollisions
Called from flixel.tile.FlxTilemap::computePathDistance line 1806
Called from flixel.tile.FlxTilemap::findPath line 796
Called from PlayState::update line 87
Called from flixel.FlxState::tryUpdate line 155
Called from flixel.FlxGame::update line 700
Called from flixel.FlxGame::step line 648
Called from flixel.FlxGame::onEnterFrame line 493
Called from openfl._legacy.events.EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent line 98
Called from openfl._legacy.display.DisplayObject::__dispatchEvent line 182
Called from openfl._legacy.display.DisplayObject::__broadcast line 161
Called from openfl._legacy.display.DisplayObjectContainer::__broadcast line 286
Called from openfl._legacy.display.Stage::__render line 1103
Called from openfl._legacy.display.Stage::__checkRender line 351
Called from openfl._legacy.display.Stage::__pollTimers line 1084
Called from openfl._legacy.display.Stage::__doProcessStageEvent line 430
Done(1)
```

Does anybody know what went wrong and why?